# Telerik MVC ComboBox in Grid not posting the right value

Tags: combobox, telerik, grid, postback

I have set up a ComboBox in grid. It shows everything fine but when I select anything in the ComboBox it is not posting the right value to the server, I debugged it and found out that it always posts value 0.
Any idea why is that and how to fix it?
Here's the important code:

```
    **Controller**
    //lista za stvaratelje (ComboBox)
    var stvaratelji = newStvarateljiService.GetAllStvaratelje();
    //za combobox
    ViewBag.stvaratelji = stvaratelji;
    //za selectlist
    var listaStvaratelja = new SelectList(stvaratelji, "IdStvaratelj", "Naziv");
    ViewData["stvaratelji"] = listaStvaratelja;

**View**
columns.ForeignKey(b => b.StvarateljId, (SelectList)ViewData["stvaratelji"]).Title("Stvaratelji").EditorTemplateName("Stvaratelji").Width("30%");

**EditorTemplate**
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

<%= Html.Telerik().ComboBoxFor(m => m)
    .Name("Stvaratelji")
    .Filterable(filtering =>
        filtering.FilterMode(AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains)
    )
    .Encode(false)
    .AutoFill(true)
    .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData["stvaratelji"])
 %>
```

I am using selectList with foreignKey because when the grid is not in edit mode it shows value (ID) instead of the name, but that's a completely different issue and one not so important. Nevertheless if someone knows how to set ComboBox to show the name when the grid is not in edit mode it would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what is the problem.
I changed the name of EditorTemplate's ComboBoxFor in "StvarateljId" because ComboBoxFor is not bound to the Title in the Grid but the name of the property in "ForeignKey" part.

Comment: Now if someone could still help me with the SelectList with Foreign key part.
I would like to use only the comboBox and not the SelectList with ForeignKey too.
When the Grid is not in edit/insert mode I would like the column to show the "Naziv" from the comboBox too.

Answer (score 0):

Dario,
To address the question in the comment of your answer ("not to use SelectList"):
Have you tried changing from a ForeignKey to a simple Bound column with a DisplayTemplates/StvarateljId similar to the EditorTemplates?  I have had some success with this setup instead of using the ForeignKey.

Here is a [link to the demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/serveredittemplates) at Telerik showing this exact setup.